# select within loop in Rails 3, taking only first option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select

Guys I have a form like this

```
<%= form_tag({:action => 'update_survey_list_status') do%>
<table id="survey_form">
  <tr>
    <th>Beneficiary Details</th>
    <th>HFI details</th>
    <th  style="vertical-align: middle">
    <input type='checkbox' name='checkall' onclick='checkedAll();'></th>
  </tr>
  <% @to_be_registred_list.each do |b| %>
  <tr>
    <td  style="vertical-align: middle"><b> <%= b.name %></b><br />
      <span><%= b.age %>, <%= b.sex %><br /><%= b.address %></span>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: middle">
      <%= select("beneficiaryloans","hfi_id",  
       Beneficiary.find(b.beneficiary_id).beneficiaryloans.collect 
       { 
         |h| [User.find(h.hfi_id).name+" - Rs. #{h.amount} @ #{h.rate} % for 
         #{h.period}", h.hfi_id] }) %>
    </td>
<td> <%= check_box_tag "benificiary_loan_ids[]", b.beneficiary_id,:name => 
      "benificiary_loan_ids[]"%> 
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
 </table>
<%end %>
```

Here, within a form, **@to_be_registred_list** will return 2 records, for each **|b|** record, within a **select tag**

**Beneficiary.find(b.beneficiary_id).beneficiaryloans.collect** will return many records. so each drop-down filled with associated values. here if I submits the form, even after selecting different records from each drop-down, it will only takes first option from each drop-down. how to solve this?

I need what I selected form each drop-down!

Answer (score 0):

Did you used the debug on rails?
Use it and check the params you're receiving